# pase two json arrays inside flutter

Tags: json, flutter, dart

hello I'm New and trying to build a flutter app with mysql db , the problem is I have a json response with two object that I want to parse into one widget and I really don't know how to make their classes can any one help me :

**Json Response :**

```
{
   "folders":[
      {
         "id":2531,
         "name":"MiniOSCE Ihsan",
         "img":null,
         "haschild":0,
         "parentid":1665,
         "createdate":"2019-11-26 12:21:27",
         "inarchive":0,
         "active":1
      }
   ],
   "files":[
      {
         "id":3669,
         "name":"Dermatology_Atlas.pdf 16.61MB",
         "img":null,
         "uploader":"admin",
         "url":"http:\/\/msc-mu.com\/..\/uploaded\/130620190Dermatology_Atlas.pdf",
         "createdate":"2019-06-13
23:54:41",
         "approved":0,
         "active":1
      },
      {
         "id":3670,
         "name":"Derma-\u062a\u0644\u062e\u064a\u0635.docx 27.88KB",
         "img":null,
         "uploader":"admin",
         "url":"http:\/\/msc-mu.com\/..\/uploaded\/130620190Derma-\u062a\u0644\u062e\u064a\u0635.docx",
         "createdate":"2019-06-13
23:54:41",
         "approved":0,
         "active":1
      },
      {
         "id":3671,
         "name":"ABC Dermatology and MiniOsce .pptx 67.43MB",
         "img":null,
         "uploader":"admin",
         "url":"http:\/\/msc-mu.com\/..\/uploaded\/130620190ABC Dermatology and MiniOsce .pptx",
         "createdate":"2019-06-13 23:54:41",
         "approved":0,
         "active":1
      },
      {
         "id":3672,
         "name":"Derma
1ry & 2ry skin lesions.pptx 2.02MB",
         "img":null,
         "uploader":"admin",
         "url":"http:\/\/msc-mu.com\/..\/uploaded\/130620190Derma 1ry & 2ry skin lesions.pptx",
         "createdate":"2019-06-13 23:54:41",
         "approved":0,
         "active":1
      },
      {
         "id":3673,
         "name":"Derma mini OSCE.docx
1.96MB",
         "img":null,
         "uploader":"admin",
         "url":"http:\/\/msc-mu.com\/..\/uploaded\/130620190Derma mini OSCE.docx",
         "createdate":"2019-06-13 23:54:41",
         "approved":0,
         "active":1
      },
      {
         "id":4955,
         "name":"immune 9 (8_9.3).m4a 45.66MB",
         "img":null,
         "uploader":"uploader18",
         "url":"http:\/\/msc-mu.com\/..\/uploaded\/231020190immune
9 (8_9.3).m4a",
         "createdate":"2019-10-23 12:01:36",
         "approved":0,
         "active":1
      }
   ]
}
```

I have did implement the folders list alone and the files alone how to do them both ? and convert them into widget

this is my widget code for files ! and some changes for folders :

```
class ListViewFolders extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<Files> filesSubject;
  ListViewFolders(this.filesSubject);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView.builder(
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int currentIndex) {
        return createFellowFolders(filesSubject[currentIndex], context);
      },
      itemCount: filesSubject.length,
    );
  }

  Widget createFellowFolders(Files files, BuildContext context) {
    String url = files.url;
    return Slidable(
      actionPane: SlidableDrawerActionPane(),
      actionExtentRatio: 0.25,
      child: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
            border: Border.all(width: 1), color: Colors.transparent.withOpacity(0.3)),
        child: ListTile(
          title: Text(
            files.name,
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
          ),
          subtitle: Text('Slide To View options',
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
        ),
      ),
      actions: <Widget>[
        IconSlideAction(
          caption: 'Play',
          color: Colors.red,
          icon: FontAwesomeIcons.play,
          onTap: () {
            toast('coming soon');
          }
        ),
      ],
      secondaryActions: <Widget>[
        IconSlideAction(
          caption: 'Download',
          color: Colors.green,
          icon: Icons.arrow_circle_down,
          onTap: () async {
            final status = await Permission.storage.request();
            if (status.isGranted) {
              final externalDir = await getExternalStorageDirectory();
              final id = await FlutterDownloader.enqueue(
                  url: files.url,
                  savedDir: externalDir.path,
                  showNotification: true,
                  openFileFromNotification: true);
            } else {
              toast('Permission Denied');
            }
          },
        ),
        IconSlideAction(
          caption: 'Share',
          color: Colors.indigo,
          icon: Icons.share,
          onTap: () {
            Share.share(url);
          },
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

**model class:**

```
import 'dart:core';

class YearsMain {
  final String id;
  final String name;


  const YearsMain({this.id, this.name});

  factory YearsMain.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> jsonData) {
    return YearsMain(
      id: jsonData['id'].toString(),
      name: jsonData['name'],
    );
  }
}



class Folders {
   String id;
   String name;
   String haschild;
  Folders({this.id, this.name,this.haschild});

  factory Folders.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json)=> Folders(id: json["id"].toString(),name: json["name"],haschild: json["haschild"].toString());
}
class Files{
  String id ;
  String name ;
  String url ;
  Files({this.id,this.name,this.url});
  factory Files.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json)=> Files(id: json["id"].toString(),name: json["name"],url: json["url"]);

}
```

Comment: Can you add your widget code?

Comment: I've added it and how to access to folders and files components within the shared class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an abstract class Entity and make File and Folder extend from it. An entity can contain all the properties common to both files and folders like id and name.

```
abstract class Entity {
  String id;
  String name;
  
  Entity({String this.id, String this.name});
}

class Folder extends Entity {
    String haschild;
    Folder({ String id, String name, this.haschild }) : super(id: id, name: name);

    factory Folder.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Folder(haschild: json["haschild"].toString(), id: json['id'].toString(), name: json['name'].toString());
}

class File extends Entity {
    String url;
    File({ String id, String name, this.url }) : super(id: id, name: name);
  
    factory File.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json)=> File(id: json["id"].toString(), name: json["name"].toString(), url: json["url"].toString());
}
```

Create a List instead of separate lists. It can contain both file and folder models because they extend from the entity and now you have a single list containing both types.

```
var data = jsonDecode(yourJson);

List<Entity> all = <Entity>[];
  
List folders = data["folders"].toList();
List files = data["files"].toList();
  
List<Folder> folders_model = folders.map((e) => Folder.fromJson(e)).toList();
List<File> files_model = files.map((e) => File.fromJson(e)).toList();

all.addAll(folders_model);
all.addAll(files_model);
```

Build your widgets like this

```
itemCount: all.length,
itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int currentIndex) {
    Entity e = all[currentIndex];
    if(e is File) {
        File f = e;
        // Create and return your widget for file // You can access all the props of your file model
    } else if(e is Folder) {
        Folder f = e;
        // Create and return your widget for folder // You can access all the props of your folder model
    }
}
```

Edit =======

Here is the minimal code in dartpad: [Code](https://dartpad.dev/235c5aed41efd9a75b6f1500814ef089)

Comment: the second code should i put it in my future function ?

Comment: in your third code does it return all files and folders ?

Comment: The second code is how you are going to get the List of the models. If you are fetching from the server, you can use Future to assign the list

Comment: The third code is just the widget building part. I have just replaced List<Files> filesSubject with List<Entity> all; and now inside this list, you have both files and folders and the third code shows how to differentiate between them.

Comment: Ultimately, you have just one list containing both files and folders and a way to differentiate between them. So, you can easily create only one list view whose children are based on what you want to do for files and folders separately.

Comment: No problem. I will post a minimal example. wait for the edit.

Comment: you did not got me ! in the third you have that if statement ! i want both lists names are in listview does your code works like that ?

Comment: You want to have a single list view to show both files and folders right? Check the code I posted. You can get the idea

Answer (score 0):

```
var json = jsonDecode(your example);
json['files'].forEach((e){
   debugPrint(e['name']);
});
```

folders are same